# Check whether keypad locked or not using AT-command

Tags: mobile-phones, at-command

How can I check whether keypad of my mobile phone is locked or not using

```
AT+CLCk
```

command.

I am using Sony Ericsson k750i which supports this command

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hey guyz i got the solution.....

AT+CLCK="CS",2

return +CLCK:0 means keypad is in unlocked condition
       +CLCK:1 means keypad is in locked condition